# Where can I find Lovecraft books in Esperanto?

Tags: books

It seems like there should be translations available given the public domain status of Lovecraft's work.

Where can I find them?

Comment: Also see this question about how to find out if any book in general is available in Esperanto: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/799/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-book-has-been-translated-to-esperanto

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. 1) the other question deals with the mere existence of a translation, whereas this question means finding it to read it. 2) The top answer on the other question is "write a library to ask". We as a community can certainly find a better response than that! As the other answers make clear, we can't even trust Amazon. This question makes sense to me. I'll be posting a question on meta to solve this topic by voting.

Comment: I am not sure there is that much difference between _How can I find out if a book has been translated to Esperanto?_ and _Where can I find Lovecraft books in Esperanto?_ The first question is telling how to find a book translation, while this is asking where to find a translation of a specific book.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I don't understand the reason for this change: "the question title doesn't count as question". Is this written somewhere as a Stack Exchange rule or recommendation?

Comment: @kiamlaluno If you don't understand it from what I have written, re-read Andrew Woods' answer to the question. For example: "However, this is a serious issue which is yet to be properly dealt with." "Furthermore, there are unscrupulous people selling machine translations of famous novels on Amazon, and it seems that luckless beginners are buying them." But that is why I want to solve this question on meta and not in the comments: http://meta.esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/142/question-looking-for-specific-literature-to-read-is-not-a-duplicate

Comment: @CharlotteSL Look at the questions on every Stack Exchange site: The question is in the question body, not the question title.

Answer (score 11):

One of Lovecraft's friends, J. F. Morton, Jr., spoke Esperanto, but I don't know if he translated any of Lovecraft's work.

- A translation by Don Harlow of [*Pickman's Model*](http://literaturo.org/HARLOW-Don/Esperanto/Literaturo/Noveloj/La_Modelo_de_Pikman.html)
- An anonymous translation of the short-short [*Memory*](https://eo.wikisource.org/wiki/Memoro)
- The opening of a translation by Sonja Elen Kisa of [*The Festival*](http://www.elerno.cn/bbs/dispbbs.asp?boardid=21&id=5117&star=1&page=23) (no longer available in full)
- A translation by Charlotte Burton and Tim Rice of *Call of Cthulhu*

  - [PDF version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwSZaLtcRKsXNDFtMElHUzVyUW8/view)
  - [ePub version](http://www.lulu.com/shop/hp-lovecraft/la-voko-de-%C4%A5tulho/ebook/product-21640232.html)

That's all I can see for the moment (which is somewhat surprising).

Be very careful about buying anything without a preview, as I think this author might eventually be targeted by the people who sell fraudulent machine-translations.

Comment: The Festival, la soleno, isn't complete, as far as I can see? (Or am I missing part of it?) The story ends abruptly for me when he is knocking on the door. http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/f.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks as though the whole of it was formerly available on her website but isn't any longer.

Comment: "Esperantist" sounds quite cult-like. It would be cool if you could change that to "Esperanto speaker."

Comment: Well...... okay.

Answer (score 7):

I used the National Library of Austria's database to search for books by Lovecraft. It returns 0 results. The other two libraries don't seem to have any online search functions.

I know that it isn't true that there is nothing of H.P. Lovecraft in Esperanto, so I searched further and asked on [Telegramo](http://www.telegramo.org/)'s Literatura Babilejo (thank you, Salva!). In addition to Andrew's suggestions, here are a few more:

[La terura maljunulo](http://literaturo.org/HARLOW-Don/Esperanto/Literaturo/Noveloj/La_Terura_Maljunulo.html) on literaturo.org, formerly Don Harlow's collection.

And [La Sorĉado de Ulua (The Witchcraft Of Ulua)](http://www.eldritchdark.com/writings/translations/esperanto/2).

This book says there is a translation of [The Colour of Space](https://books.google.de/books?id=Xz3JO9gRyHMC&pg=PA372&lpg=PA372&dq=lovecraft%20esperanto&source=bl&ots=oLBNrC5X3I&sig=luE__FfYg_Zw3k63Tds1EMpkS1E&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx6sDohNPPAhXByRoKHQrtDG8Q6AEIYDAJ#v=onepage&q=lovecraft%20esperanto&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

I've begun translating his complete fiction. I intend to publish it as a single volume in hardcover. I'm already looking for a publisher. I've completed several of the shorter stories and am working on The Shadow over Innsmouth now.

Comment: “Keep your goals to yourself.”
--Derek Sivers

https://www.ted.com/talks/derek_sivers_keep_your_goals_to_yourself?language=en